# Should something be done about the anonymity and anonymous tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonym-request

- [anonymity](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/anonymity)
- [anonymous](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/anonymous)

Feels like anonymous & anonymity could be folded to [privacy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/privacy). I can't propose it as I lack the rep.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest we make both of them synonyms of [privacy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/privacy), which is the larger overall concept.

I created tag synonym suggestions at +6/-0. [Vote for them here](https://superuser.com/tags/privacy/synonyms).

Comment: Great idea. I was looking for a broader term but couldn't remember "privacy"

Comment: @DanielBeck: We need a `total answer score of 5 or more on the tag`, seems we'll have to resort to waiting for moderators to apply the synonym...

Comment: @TomWijsman True, I saw that and it's unlikely (not impossible). Still, worth a try.

Comment: @TomWijsman (and everyone else) [You could support this topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79151/add-the-ability-to-create-any-tag-synonym-to-the-trusted-user-privileges) I just found. It's a sensible idea and would be quite useful for situations like this one.

Comment: Voted that one up. :)

Comment: Oh wow. I hadn't even understood that process completely. Definitely voted that one up.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Please remove the accept checkmark for the time being, since this issue hasn't been resolved yet. We still might need diamond moderator support, there are no upvotes for the synonym suggestions.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Synonyms are active. Success!